# How to can I print emails in Geary?

Tags: pantheon-mail, printer

I cannot seem to find any option to print emails from Geary.

Comment: please see my answer and let me know, Is that you want?

Comment: Please mark the answer as solving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open an email, click on downward arrow--> print.

[image: Imgur]